# How do I extend JQuery's ajax done() method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a jQuery ajax function like this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
            url : '/blabla',
            method : 'post',
            data: {
                bla : bla
            }
        }).done(function(data) {
            // do lots of stuff
        });
```

.. and I want to be able to add a check that the data passed into the done callback function doesn't have a session_timed_out value in it. Say I have many functions similar to the one above but they all do different things, but they ALL need to check if the session timed out first. Is there a proper way to extend done() so it initially checks for a timeout? I tried to do something like this but it failed:

```
var myAjax = function(options,callback){ 
    var defaults = {              
        done: function(data){  //hijack the success handler?
            if(check(data)){    
                callback(data); 
            }
        }
    };
    jQuery.extend(options,defaults);  
    return jQuery.ajax(options); 
}
```

When I use this extended function it works like before, meaning the check never gets called because it seems to be superseded by the done() callback in the actual implementation, which I guess makes sense. So I want to know if there is a way to "decorate" or extend done() function so it initially checks for the session timeout first. Or will I need to manually add this same session check to all of my ajax done's?

Comment: FYI the method I implemented above is from : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815058/extending-jquery-ajax-success-globally

Comment: jquery has global handlers - see http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/ I have used them for a similar authentication case. This doesn't decorate but rather it allows interception.

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12487794/overriding-jquery-functions-best-practice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This snippet overrides the jQuery ajax method so you can add an extra check when it successfully returns.

```
(function($) {

    var yourCustomCheck = function(ajaxRes) {
        // Do whatever you need and return a boolean
    };

    var oldAjax = $.ajax;
    $.ajax = function(opts) {
        return $.Deferred(function() {
            var _def = this;

            oldAjax.call(this, opts).done(function(res) {
                console.log("this is done first");
                if(yourCustomCheck.call(this, res)) _def.resolve(res);
                else _def.reject("timeout");
            }).fail(function() {
                _def.reject();
            });
        })
    }

})(jQuery);
```

After this, you can use `$.ajax()` normally..

```
$.ajax({
    .....
}).done(function(res) {
    console.log("ok");
}).fail(function() {
    console.log("no ok");
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle with a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/jormaechea/kffyo7qL/1/

Comment: I will see if I can get this to work. Currently, when I do this: console.log(ajaxRes); inside the yourCustomCheck() method - I don't get the ajax response, I get the html of the page that I am currently on. I will see if I can fix it.

Comment: Just modified this to fix what you reported.. Please check it again and let me know..

Comment: I'm sorry Juaquin. I am still getting the html of the page I am on when I console log the ajaxRes var. I appreciate your effort, and will upvote you for it.

Comment: Weird.. Just tested it again in jsfiddle and worked ok.. I updated my answer with the test case link..

Comment: @JoelJoelBinks - This is what is considered a [promise anti-pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns) because it creates a new promise rather than use one that is already returned when that is not necessary.  It's not a good habit to get into.  Also, replace `$.ajax()` with a substitute that has different behavior than the standard means your code will not be compatible with ANY third party library that also uses jQuery ajax.  This is also not considered a good practice.  It is better to create a new function with the new behavior.

Comment: Upvote for the advice @jfriend00, I meant to include it  as a warning but just forgotten.. Will update soon.

Answer (score 1):

You could chain a timeout checker:

```
   jQuery.ajax({
        url : '/blabla',
        method : 'post',
        data: {
            bla : bla
        }
    }).then(timeoutCheck).then(function(data) {
        // do lots of stuff
    }, function(err) {
        // handle error
    });

    function timeoutCheck(data) {
        if (check(data)) {
           return data;
        } else {
           // return a rejected promise to turn fulfilled into reject
           return jQuery.Deferred.reject(new Error("timeout"));
        }
    }
```

---

Or, you could put this in your own ajax wrapper.

```
jQuery.ajaxT = function() {
     return jQuery.ajax.apply(jQuery, arguments).then(timeoutCheck);
}

jQuery.ajaxT(...).then(function(results) {
    // handle returned data here
    // the timeoutCheck has already been done
}, function(err) {
    // handle any errors here
});
```

Then, any ajax call you initiated with `jQuery.ajaxT()` would automatically have the timeoutCheck added to it's promise logic.  If the ajax call succeeds and the timeout check passes, then the promise is fulfilled.  If the ajax call succeeds and the timeout check fails, then the promise rejected.

Comment: @user2864740 - yes it would, but it's a lot cleaner than what the OP was doing and it provides a channel for proper error handling on any given request.  It's one extra `.then(timeoutCheck)` for the ajax calls that you want this check run on.  One could wrap `jQuery.ajax()` with a custom wrapper function and do it there too and then just call the custom wrapper function when you want this extra code.

Comment: @user2864740 - I added a function wrapper that includes the functionality built in.